# Weinberg Chapter 10: Sign convention for momentum operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, metric-tensor, conventions

Weinberg says that translational invariance produces a conserved momentum, i.e., $P^\mu$, such that (Eq. 10.1.1):
\begin{align*}
    [P_\mu, O(x)] = +i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} O(x). \tag{10.1.1}
\end{align*}
But generally in QM, we had used $ -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} O(x)$, I just want to make sure that this is *because Weinberg chooses the passive view*. Weinberg uses the $(-,+,+,+)$ sign convention. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: What sign convention does Weinberg use for the translation operator as an exponential of the momentum operator? What sign convention does Weinberg use for the metric?

Comment: Also how does Weinberg define $T(x)f(x_0)$? As $f(x_0+x)$ or as $f(x_0-x)$?

Answer (score 0):

> Weinberg says that translational invariance produces a conserved momentum, i.e., $P^\mu$, such that (Eq. 10.1.1):
> \begin{align*}
>     [P_\mu, O(x)] = +i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} O(x). \tag{10.1.1}
> \end{align*}
> But generally in QM, we had used $ -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} O(x)$,

Not "generally," but rather "conventionally."

It is a convention to make the following two choices:

(1) Sign convention in the generator of translations:
$$
\hat T(x) = e^{+i x \hat p/\hbar}
$$

(2) Sign convention in the position representation of $\hat p$:
$$
\hat p = -i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}
$$

You can flip **both** these signs without changing the end result that $\hat T$ generates space translations:
$$
\hat T(x)f(a)=f(a+x)\;.
$$

You can also flip **one** of these signs to make
$$
\hat T(x)f(a) = f(a-x);.
$$

Because you haven't told us the rest of the context of Weinberg's book we can't say whether the convention is due to a different exponential sign or due to passive vs active. This might also be related to Weinberg's choice of metric...

Comment: The metric in his QFT text is mostly plus, i.e. diag (-,+,+,+).

Comment: Heck yeah, the good metric!

Comment: I think these signs relate to passive and active view. Weinberg does take passive view, where the frame moves, and we get basically what you just said. Thanks, I just wanted to confirm.